# Is there a way to run F# code from a C# program?

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I use Rider and/or Visual Studio for Mac to run my C# code. I can individually create an F# project if needed. How do I run the F# code within the C# main program:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //F() = function that executes F# code
        Console.WriteLine(F());
    }
}
```

And F# code:
`printf("Hello, World!\n")` or any code really

I tried this in the terminal:
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRU4F.jpg)
[VS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8WCQ.jpg)

Comment: Let your C# program have a reference to the F# program, then just call the method.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, how?

Comment: @RedMermaid By [reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference)

Comment: You can have mixed projects in a solution. Create a F# project, put it into your solution, reference it and you should be good to go.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley  does it work for C++?

Comment: Why C++ now? Do you have a C# program or a C++ program. The code looks like C#, not C++. Anyway, the answer is: no, that's not so simple. You would need C++/CLI or COM objects for that.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley, I tried it, and was successful now what?

Comment: Profit! .......

Comment: @RobertHarvey not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an F# class library, add your F# code.
Create a C# console (or whatever) app, reference the F# class library, and call the f# code from your C# code.
you may need a 'using' statement to get your F# code accessible.

C#/F# code both compile to similar binary files (PE code, or something like that), which are mostly accessible from the other language, there are some features of both languages that don't translate (SRTPs being the most obvious thing not accessible from C#).

Interoperability though is at this binary level, you can't just write F# code in a C# source file or vice versa (though this is possible in some other languages).

instructions:

create F# class library called "ClassLibrary1"

in Visual Studio

```
namespace ClassLibrary1

module Say =
    let hello name =
        printfn "Hello %s" name
```

**ADD** C# console app called "ConsoleApp1" to the same solution

Add project reference from consoleapp1 to classlibrary1

your C# project file should look something like this (obviously it may be slightly different but the crucial bit is the project reference)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

build

paste this code into your C# code

```
using ClassLibrary1;

Say.hello("Mr D");
```

If you can't get it to work do this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-7-0

get that working, then just do the first bit with an F# class library instead of a C# one

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I tried both C# and F# console apps (as test runs) and they gave the error in the VS_error link (should be an image), now I'll try the F# library. One more nuance, does the F# need to be in the project folder of the C# console app project? Or can I reference it in the terminal via the command: dotnet add app/app.csproj reference lib/lib.csproj ?

Comment: ive added explicit instructions...personally id avoid using command line stuff until you know roughly what u are doing (I only use it for scripts), visual studio is your friend, and there to make it easy, I've not put anything in special folders except the default one VS gives me, just make sure you "add' the C# project to the solution dont just create a new one, and VS will wire it all up for you